# Regular expression in python removes too much

Tags: python, c++, regex

I'm trying too clean C++ files for compilation on linux. Specifically I'm trying to replace backslashes '\'with slashes '/' in #include statements with a python script (I have to use python).
Unfortunately the script removes almost everything in the except for the last bracket:

```
}
```

I am using this script:

```
import os
import re
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(".\Source", topdown=True):
    for file in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        tempfile = file + ".bak"
        with open(tempfile, "w") as target:
            with open(file) as source:
                for line in source:
                    if "#include" in line:
                        re.sub("\\\\", "/", line)
                target.write(line)
        os.remove(file)
        os.rename(tempfile, file)
```

Edit:
After implementing Simon Fraser's suggestions, the script works fine now. It looks like this:

```
import os
import re
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(".\Source", topdown=True):
    for file in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        tempfile = file + ".bak"
        with open(tempfile, "w") as target:
            with open(file) as source:
                for line in source:
                    if "#include" in line:
                        line = re.sub(r"\\", "/", line)
                    target.write(line)
        os.remove(file)
        os.rename(tempfile, file)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the regex library for this method? As it can easily be done using a for loop as well

Comment: Is the code in the question indented pproperly? Because `target.write(line)` is not inside the `for` loop, so is only going to write out the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this section:

```
for line in source:
    if "#include" in line:
        re.sub("\\\\", "/", line)
target.write(line)
```

Inside the `for` loop, nothing is written to the file `target`. Once the `for` loop ends, the last value of `line` is written out, which is likely why you've got just the last `}` in the output.

If you move the `target.write` inside the `for` loop things should work. `re.sub` also *returns* the new value rather than replacing `line`, so you need a variable assignment there, too.

```
for line in source:
    if "#include" in line:
        line = re.sub("\\\\", "/", line)
    target.write(line)
```

Strings also have a `.replace` method, which may be faster:

```
for line in source:
    if '#include' in line:
        line = line.replace('\\','/')
    target.write(line)
```

Comment: That fixed all of my problems. Thank you.